# YouTubers’ Life Update meaning

Tags: meaning

Some YouTubers upload “life update”. What does it mean?
Is it like “I made a big decision about my life” or “I show you my daily life” or “I’ve grown so much”?

Answer (score 1):

"I show you my daily life" is called a vlog. I've never heard of "I've grown so much" unless you mean it in a bodybuilding context. And a "life update" sounds much more toward the "I made a big decision about my life" area. I believe that when one uses that phrase, the decision has already been made and the video is about an update regarding that decision and its consequences.

Answer (score 1):

I think he/she want to show his/her daily life, so it called life update. It means you update your daily life to your audience. It can be in form of vlog, like daily vlog